# Asymptotic average of cosine function

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I am wondering whether the following equality is true and how it can be proved:

$$
\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T \cos(2t)=0.
$$

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \sum\limits_{t=1}^T \cos(2\pi t)=1$ so you may need to use some properties of $\cos$ or $\pi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\cos(2t) = \Re (e^{i 2t})$. The series can therefore be considered a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. Indeed, using this can prove the sum is bounded, and thus the limit is zero.